# Retrieve the DOM from a variable with Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom, domparser, simpledom

I'm using Simple HTML DOM Parser to retrieve informations from a website with this code:

```
$html = file_get_html("http://www.example.com/"]);
$table = $html->find("div[class=table]");

foreach ( $table as $tabella ) {
    $title = $tabella->find (".elementTitle");
    echo "<h2>" . $title[0] -> plaintext . "</h2>"; 
    $minisito = $tabella->find ("h1[class=elementTitle] a");
    echo "<p>" . $minisito[0] -> href . "</p>";     
}
```

Now I need to extract other pieces of contents from the url contained in this specific urls `$minisito[0] -> href`

How can I create another variable using `file_get_html` command to extract data from this new urls?

Comment: The same way you did the first time?

Comment: If you say once more `$html1 = file_get_html("http://www.example.com/"]);`, another object will be created. and you will be available to use it referencing to $html1

Comment: You can try to convert this to a function, and make a call same function by it self.

Comment: @splash58 Yes, I tried with a new variable `$html1` but the problem (I'm a newbie with php) is that the url I want to scrape is inside the first dom and I need to retrieve it with this variable `$minisito = $tabella->find ("h1[class=elementTitle] a");`. 

I tried with:

`$html1 = file_get_html($minisito[0] -> href);` but doesn't work.

Comment: what is a result of `echo "<p>" . $minisito[0] -> href . "</p>";` ?

Comment: @splash58 is an url like http://www.example.com

Comment: does it have `http://` at start?

Comment: Yes it have an https://

Comment: How does it not work - $html1 is false?

Comment: @splash58 I tried again with `$html1 = file_get_html($minisito[0] -> href);` and it works

Comment: I's Ok.  Good luck!